# Error 0x2 starting node.exe -v in Git bash for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, git, bash

I have installed Gitbash for windows version 2.7 and installed nodejs 5.5 on windows 7 64 bit machine.

when I try to run

```
 node -v
```

i get the the error msg

```
Error 0x2 starting node.exe -v
```

I am not sure why is this happening, I uninstalled and re installed both node and git, restarted my system and checked my env variables. everything seems fine. 
My PATH env variable in 'User Environment variable' looks like this.

```
C:\Users\<userid>\.dnx\bin;C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\npm ;C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Would https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/403#issuecomment-138830833 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize that npm was missing in my PATH variable. somehow, nodejs didn't add its value to my PATH Variable
more info [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4356)

After adding it to my USER PATH variable. Everything seems working.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error after reinstalling node.js without restarting my Git bash session. After closing and reopening the terminal, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Turns out that node had been extracted an extra file deep - so it was node12.x.x-win-x86/node12.x.x-win-x86 and my system was confused when i tried to call it.

Fixed my issue by changing the name of the exterior folder, then moving the internal folder out one. Didn’t even need to update %path% as I’d got that right the first time.